# echo json_encode($return_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); character 'e' in digits not working

Tags: php, json, postgresql

one of row of my db has contacts table has character varying column as phone with value 3162e6313358

```
$return_data = array('phone' => $contact_phone);
echo json_encode($return_data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

this code does not give me any output.
I searched for this people gave solutions like ('phone' => '".$contact_phone."')
this is working.
I don't want to typecast for every array element
But i need generic solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Json encode is returning with boolean if it fails. Anyway, if I run this code with the given value: `Warning: json_encode() [function.json-encode]: double INF does not conform to the JSON spec, encoded as 0`

Comment: on my system this in not giving warning as well the output is simply blank.  this is i tried php -a                                                                                                                                                                             
Interactive shell

php > $a = ['a'=>"1", 'b'=>NULL, 'c'=>"3162e6313358"];
php > echo json_encode($a, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

Comment: maybe your error displayning is turned off.

Comment: why do you need JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK when the data can have letters?

Comment: Why does a phone number have the value "3162e6313358" to begin with?! That points to some deeper underlying problems in your system.

Comment: hi SNAG, this is not the case for only phone number. I have many other columns which are numeric values example archive_status with value 0 or 1 etc.

Comment: Hi deceze, i don't have a control on input data. so user can insert any data.

Comment: The issue comes from `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` and, in fact, its usage hides a deeper problem in the code: you store numbers as strings. Most probably they come from the database and your code does not change their types before working with them. My suggestion is to use `intval()`/`floatval()` or other method to convert numeric strings fetched from user input, database etc. to numbers for numeric properties (IDs, amounts etc). On an OOP approach this is usually easy as there are only a few places where a value is stored in a property (constructor, setters etc).

Comment: @axiac Phone numbers should not be stored as ints, since they usually have leading zeros and/or possibly specific formatting.

Comment: @deceze Did I say that? I used "numbers" with its most general meaning. I didn't mention anything about "phone". _"Convert strings to numbers for **numeric** properties"_. Phone numbers are not numbers, even if they have this name, for the reasons you mentioned; also, they don't follow the semantic of numbers: there is no point adding or multiplying two phone "numbers".

Comment: @axiac Quote: *"its usage hides a deeper problem in the code: you store numbers as strings"* - sounds to me like you were suggesting to store telephone numbers as ints. :)

Comment: @deceze Nope, it's about the numeric values like IDs, counts, numeric status codes a.s.o. (as illustrated on the 3rd sentence)

Answer (score 2):

#### Option 1 (the best)

1. Convert numeric values (IDs, counts, numeric status codes, booleans a.s.o.) to numbers as soon as you get them from user input (`$_GET[]`, `$_POST[]`) or from database. When they are extracted from user input the conversion should be part of the data validation anyway.
2. Keep phone "numbers" as strings; they are not numbers, after all, they are just strings of digits, with or without starting zeroes and non-digit characters in the middle or at the end. Also keep as strings other values that looks numeric but are, in fact, not numbers: credit card numbers, for example.
3. Remove the `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` parameter from the call to `json_encode()`; if you implement #1 above you don't need it any more.

#### Option 2 (workaround)

Append a space character (`' '`) to the phone number when you get it from the database. It won't make much difference (if any at all) when it is displayed in a web page.

`json_encode()` won't believe it is a floating point number any more, not even if it starts with `+` or `0`.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I had already completed most of the part of my application, and to change values of those many columns of many tables or to change code of user input is much time consuming and that is my last option.

Comment: @maheshkajale It will be easier to maintain if you go ahead and rectify the underlying problem now.