# Postgres error 22P02 `Escape sequence "\\e" is invalid.`

Tags: json, postgresql, orm

I am trying to insert a json array in a Vercel Postgres database, using drizzle ORM.

Here is the schema:

```js
export const Table = pgTable(
  "t",
  {
    id: serial("id").primaryKey(),
    text: text("text"),
    items: json("items").array(),
  }
);
```

Here is the stringified `.items` field I want to insert:

```bash
[{"type":"text","text":"Matrix is $$\\begin{bmatrix}\n    a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14} & a_{15} \\\\\n    a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} & a_{24} & a_{25} \\\\\n    a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} & a_{34} & a_{35} \\\\\n    a_{41} & a_{42} & a_{43} & a_{44} & a_{45} \\\\\n    a_{51} & a_{52} & a_{53} & a_{54} & a_{55} \\\\\n\\end{bmatrix}$$"}]
```

And here is the error I get when I insert the record using Drizzle ORM:

```bash
error: invalid input syntax for type json
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@neondatabase+serverless@0.5.6/node_modules/@neondatabase/serverless/index.js:4118:25)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async VercelPgPreparedQuery.execute (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/drizzle-orm@0.28.6_@types+pg@8.10.2_@vercel+postgres@0.4.1_pg@8.11.3_postgres@3.3.5/node_modules/drizzle-orm/vercel-postgres/index.mjs:45:26)
    at async POST (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./app/api/exercise/create/route.ts:56:23)
    at async eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next@13.4.19_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/future/route-modules/app-route/module.js:254:37) {
  length: 246,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '22P02',
  detail: 'Escape sequence "\\e" is invalid.',
  hint: undefined,
  position: undefined,
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: 'JSON data, line 1: ... a_{51} & a_{52} & a_{53} & a_{54} & a_{55} \\\\n\\e...\n' +
    "unnamed portal parameter $4 = '...'",
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'jsonfuncs.c',
  line: '627',
  routine: 'json_ereport_error'
}
```

What does `Escape sequence "\\e" is invalid.` mean? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It appears that `\\end` is getting interpreted as `\\e` and `nd` separately

Comment: I checked the JSON on http://json.parser.online.fr/, it is valid!

Comment: @richyen if i do `\\fnd` instead of `\\end`, it works, why so?
Does the postgres JSON parser have a problem with the `e` character?

Comment: Seems like a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27921943/11348232

Answer (score 0):

***The problem seems to be*** Drizzle ORM reformating the values before saving them to the DB. That ended up feeding Postgres with invalid JSON whereas it was valid before giving it to Drizzle ORM.

*Another related problem I had was having `n` characters instead of `\n` in my db.*

This worked for me:

```js
import { sql } from "@vercel/postgres";
await sql`
      UPDATE t
      SET text = ${text}, items = ${items}
      WHERE id = ${id}
      RETURNING *`;
```

[I opened an issue here](https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/issues/1203) to report this bug.